# Calculating Sample Size from Prediction Equation (multifactorial linear regression)

Tags: sample-size

I am conducting a study that seeks to assess differences in fat distribution in transgender women, as compared to cisgender men and women. A prior study has previously published separate formulas derived from multifactorial linear regression of 3 predictor variables (age, BMI, and sex assigned at birth) for cisgender men (R^2=0.879) and cisgender women (R^2=0.926), but my study will be focusing on the fat distributions of transgender women, which has never been documented in the literature.

I was wondering how to calculate the sample size to assess for (1) differences in actual vs predicted values for trans women using these formulae and (2) how many subjects I would need to calculate my own multifactorial linear regression with the same 3 variables amongst transgender women?

Using G-Power and R^2 values from the article (with a=0.05 and B=0.05) for point #1, I got sample sizes of 7 and 8 for each formula, but this seems very low. Am I doing this wrong and would this mean 15 subjects total?

Comment: It may help others assist you if you provide screenshots of your input/output in GPower.